# Как включить Apache под Linux в терминале

Tags: linux, сервер

Сделал reboot сервера
Он перезагрузился, как включить Apache
Команда # service httpd start не помогает
Пишет Starting httpd:
и домен не грузиться всё равно (показывает белую страницу) http://82.146.58.128/
Помогите

Comment: начните с просмотра логов apache. а ещё лучше — добавьте в вопрос расшифровку того, что **именно** вы подразумеваете под словосочетанием «не грузится». внести правку можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: грузиться всё равно (показывает белую страницу)

Comment: В логах всё норм, может я чего не запустил?

Comment: там стоит Fedora

Comment: Fedora? А Ваш апач пишет centos. Ну и вроде как работает же. Просто страница пустая. Её наверное php генерит. X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.40